# returning cov and std from sklearn gaussian process?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics

I can return the covariance or the standard deviation from a GP using sklearn, like:

```
y, cov = gp.predict(Xpredict,return_cov=True)
y, std = gp.predict(Xpredict,return_std=True)
```

but how can I return both without calling `gp.predict` twice?

This

```
y, cov, std = gp.predict(Xpredict, return_cov=True, return_std=True)
```

doesn't work

Comment: "Note that at most one of the two can be requested."

Answer (score 2):

You can return covariance and then extract standard deviation as follow:

```
import numpy as np

y_mean, y_cov = gp.predict(X, return_cov=True)
y_std = np.sqrt(np.diag(y_cov))
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.predict), you cannot do it in one call using [`predict()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841/sklearn/gaussian_process/_gpr.py#L275)

> Note that at most one of the two can be requested.