# How to output mean and stdv of Gaussian Process Classifier in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, gaussian-process

Im fitting some data for a classification task using Gaussian Process Classifiers in sklearn. I know that for the Gaussian Process **Regressor** one can pass `return_std` in

```
y_test, std = gp.predict(x_test, return_std=True)
```

to output the standard deviation of the test sample ([like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60859206/returning-cov-and-std-from-sklearn-gaussian-process))

However, I couldn't find such a parameter for the GP **Classifier**.

Is there such thing as outputting the predictive mean and stdv of test data from a GP Classifiers? And is there a way to output the posterior mean and covariance of the fitted model?

Comment: In classifier problems, statistical features like mean or stdv don't make sense, since numbers are only used for encoding. That's why you can't find it.

Comment: @AlexSerraMarrugat thanks for your answer! Is there however any way to get the underlying mean and variance of the fitted GP?

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer you question, but if I have to guess, I will say there isn't anyway to get the mean or variance.

Comment: Thanks @AlexSerraMarrugat. I'd like to know more about why there possibly aren't any such statistical features of the underlying posterior of a fitted Classifier.. can you maybe hint me to ressources where I can learn about this?

Answer (score 0):

There is not standard deviation for categorical data, hence there is no the parameter return_std in the Classifier.

However, if you want to quantify the uncertainty of the classifier predictions, you could use the `.predict_proba(X)`method. Once you get the probabilites of each posible class you could compute the [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) of the predicted probabilities.

Comment: Hi @Adrian Pascual, thanks for your answer! Im not quite sure why GP can't give uncertainty measures in classification tasks.. why use them in the first place then. Do you have any idea *why*?

Comment: And how can I understand the idea with using entropy? Could you please give me some guidance as to how I would use this?

Comment: You mean something like entropy [in this area](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0020025509005428) ?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the variance associated with the logit function by going to the predict_proba function definition in _gpc.py and returning the 'var_f_star' value. I have modified the predict_proba and created a function to return the logit variance below:

```
    def predict_var(self, X):
    """Return probability estimates for the test vector X.

    Parameters
    ----------
    X : array-like of shape (n_samples, n_features) or list of object
        Query points where the GP is evaluated for classification.

    Returns
    -------
    C : array-like of shape (n_samples, n_classes)
        Returns the probability of the samples for each class in
        the model. The columns correspond to the classes in sorted
        order, as they appear in the attribute ``classes_``.
    """
    check_is_fitted(self)

    # Based on Algorithm 3.2 of GPML
    K_star = self.kernel_(self.X_train_, X)  # K_star =k(x_star)
    f_star = K_star.T.dot(self.y_train_ - self.pi_)  # Line 4
    v = solve(self.L_, self.W_sr_[:, np.newaxis] * K_star)  # Line 5
    # Line 6 (compute np.diag(v.T.dot(v)) via einsum)
    var_f_star = self.kernel_.diag(X) - np.einsum("ij,ij->j", v, v)
```